# AES Decryption in python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, flask, pycrypto

I'm sending credential from front-end using $.ajax method and i used to encrypt credentials using crypto.js.

javascript code

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "This is a key123", { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB});

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/test",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:JSON.stringify({key:encrypted.toString()}),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
```

same credential i want to decrypt at back-end side which is in python flask.

python code

```
data = request.json
key = data["key"]
obj2 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB)
s = obj2.decrypt(key)
print s
```

i have used same mode while encryption and decryption, but print s will print bellow string.

```
 �Qg%��qNˮ�Ŵ�M��ĦP�
                  "~�JB���w���#]�v?W
```

can anyone suggest me better way to do encryption-decryption in front-end && back-end?

i tried same encryption-decryption in python only,

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB)
>>> message = "The answer is no"
>>> ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
>>> ciphertext
'\x1f\x99%8\xa8\x197%\x89U\xb6\xa5\xb6C\xe0\x88'
>>> obj2 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB)
>>> obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
'The answer is no'
```

its working fine, but i want to encrypt data in front-end using javascript and i want to use same decryption technique in python.

Comment: `encrypted.toString()` is a bad way to converted ciphertext into string. Use Base64 or HEX text representation, and convert it in JS and python code accordingly.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin can u suggest me any working example?

Answer (score 0):

The string you pass to `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` is not directly used as the key (after utf8 encoding) as the Python code probably does, but instead is used as password to derive a key in some manner. See: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Cipher_Input.

Furthermore the output is also encoded as a string of printable characters and does not represent a string of raw bytes that the Python code requires. See: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Cipher_Output.

Comment: i read that documentation but i don't how to use it on javascript side and python side. can you please suggest me good article or working example on this ?

Comment: On a greater scale, what problem are you trying to solve? It sounds like retrieving and posting all your data over https would fulfill your confidentiality requirement and fix a few other security issues I assume you have. @Jaydipsinh

Comment: see, i want to encrypt aws credentials given by user and need to pass that encrypted credentials to server which is in flask, there i have to decrypt credentials. that's what i want to do

Comment: So transmit the credentials over https, that will ensure an authenticated and encrypted connection utilizing TLS which will be better designed and more secure than anything one will build on one's own. @Jaydipsinh